# Custom react Tab component is not accepting "dissabledTabs" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a tab component as follows:

**tab/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import TabHeader from './header';
import TabBody from './body';
import TabHeaderList from './header/list';
import TabBodyList from './body/list';
import style from './tab.css';

/**
 * Tabs are a great way to allow the user to switch between several pages that are full screen.
 */
export default class Tabs extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentTab: props.active || 0,
            disabledTabs: props.disabledTabs || []
        };
        this.ctx = {
            onChange: this.onChange
        };

        this.headerClick = this.headerClick.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(tab) {
        console.log('onChange: ', tab);
    }

    headerClick(e, onActivation, index){
        console.log("e:::::::::::::",e);
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        if(this.state.currentTab === index || this.state.disabledTabs.indexOf(index) !== -1) return false;
        let handled = null;
        if (onActivation) {
            handled = onActivation(index, this.state.currentTab);
        }
        if (handled) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            this.setState({currentTab: parseInt(index, 10)});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const type = this.props.type || 'default';
        let justified = this.props.align || '';
        if(justified === 'justified'){
            justified = 'flex1';
        }
        if(this.props.children.length !== 2) return null;

        const TabHeaderListTag = this.props.children[0];
        const TabBodyListTag = this.props.children[1];
        const {disabledTabs, currentTab } = this.state;

        console.log("---------------------");
        console.log(this.props);
        console.log("---------------------");
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log("---------------------");

        return (TabHeaderListTag.type === TabHeaderList && TabBodyListTag.type === TabBodyList ? (<div className={style.container}>
            <div className={style.headerContainer}>
                {
                    TabHeaderListTag.props.children.map((Header, i) => (Header.type === TabHeader ? (<button key={i} className={ [
                            'ft-sz-14',style[type],justified, style.header, disabledTabs.indexOf(i) !==-1?'disabled':'', currentTab === i ? style.active: ''
                        ].join(' ') } onClick={evnt => { this.headerClick(evnt, Header.props.onActivation, i) }} > {Header} </button>) : null)
                    )
                }
            </div>
            <div className={style.bodyContainer}>
                {
                    TabBodyListTag.props.children.map((Body, i) => (
                            Body.type === TabBody ? (<div key={i} className={`bg-white width100 ${(currentTab === i) ? '': 'display-none'}`}> {Body} </div>) : null
                        )
                    )
                }
            </div>
        </div>):null);
    }

};
```

**tab/body/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

**tab/body/list/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return props.children;
};
```

**tab/header/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return props.children;
};
```

**tab/header/list/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

> But when I'm using it as follows:

```
class Sam extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'Initial'
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onActivation = this.onActivation.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e){
        console.log('onChange', e.target.value);
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    }

    onActivation(cur, old){
        console.log('onActivation', cur, old);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <input style={{marginLeft: '4rem'}} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <Tab align="justified" type="gray" active={1} disabledTabs={[2]}>
                <TabHeaderList>
                    <TabHeader onActivation={this.onActivation}><Icon name="contact" width="25" height="25" color="gray" /></TabHeader>
                    <TabHeader><Icon name="dial" width="25" height="25" color="gray" /></TabHeader>
                    <TabHeader> <div>Disabled</div> </TabHeader>
                </TabHeaderList>
                <TabBodyList>
                    <TabBody className="pad-left-1r">
                        <h4>Testing Button {this.state.value}</h4>
                        <p>
                            Sample tab body
                        </p>
                    </TabBody>
                    <TabBody className="pad-left-1r">
                        <h4>Testing Button 2</h4>
                        <p>
                            This is just to demonstarate the use of tabs.
                            You could also make a `ul` inside like this:
                        </p>
                    </TabBody>
                    <TabBody className="pad-left-1r">
                        <h2>Im disabledTab</h2>
                    </TabBody>
                </TabBodyList>
            </Tab>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

it throws following error:

> `Component(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You`
>   `may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`
>
> I'm unable to find where I'm returning undefined actually so it is throwing error.
>
> But when I'm removing `disabledTabs={[2]}` in component `Sam` it works fine i.e. as follows:

```
<div>
            <input style={{marginLeft: '4rem'}} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <Tab align="justified" type="gray" active={1} >
                <TabHeaderList>
                    <TabHeader onActivation={this.onActivation}><Icon name="contact" width="25" height="25" color="gray" /></TabHeader>
                    <TabHeader><Icon name="dial" width="25" height="25" color="gray" /></TabHeader>
                </TabHeaderList>
                <TabBodyList>
                    <TabBody className="pad-left-1r">
                        <h4>Testing Button {this.state.value}</h4>
                        <p>
                            Sample tab body
                        </p>
                    </TabBody>
                    <TabBody className="pad-left-1r">
                        <h4>Testing Button 2</h4>
                        <p>
                            This is just to demonstarate the use of tabs.
                            You could also make a `ul` inside like this:
                        </p>
                    </TabBody>
                </TabBodyList>
            </Tab>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can't map over `children` like an ordinary array. You need to use `React.Children.map(children, callback)`. Check this documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: but it works if I remove disabledTabs

Comment: I did put ur changes sir, still nor working :(

Answer (score 1):

Changed some component as follows it worked:

**tab/body/list/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return <div>props.children</div>;
};
```

**tab/header/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default (props) => {
    return <div>props.children</div>;
};
```

These component was returning undefined incase of single child